# Swift sub-modules in Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, swift2, commoncrypto, podspec

I'm trying to set up the following arrangement of private Cocoapods:

`PodA` depends on `PodB` which depends on `CommonCrypto`.

`CommonCrypto` is a `dylib` that ships with iOS but doesn't have a `Swift` header module. Within `PodB` I've created a custom `module.modulemap` with the following contents:

```
module CommonCrypto [system] {
    header "/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
}
```

`PodB` passes the lint test (`pod spec lint PodB.podspec`) after adding the following lines:

```
# Ensure module isn't deleted by CocoaPods
s.preserve_paths = 'path_to/PodB/CommonCrypto'
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/path_to/CommonCrypto' }
```

Within `PodA`, I depend on `PodB` with `s.dependency = 'PodB'`. When linting `PodA` with `pod spec lint --sources=myrepo PodA.podspec` I get an error compiling any `Swift` file with `import PodB`:

```
missing required module 'CommonCrypto'
```

How can I go about fixing this? It doesn't matter to me if `CommonCrypto` is private or public to `PodB`.

I tried adding `export *` to `module.modulemap` but that made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with a (slightly) ugly workaround; I exported the include path to the parent project.

Since include paths are multi-valued, a list as opposed to a single setting, Cocoapods can merge whatever the parent project (`PodA`) sets with whatever the subproject (`PodB`) requires.

I had tried this solution before but it failed since I was using `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` instead of `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS`. The relevant bit of the fixed podspec looks like this:

```
# Ensure module isn't deleted by CocoaPods
s.preserve_paths = 'path_to/PodB/CommonCrypto'
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/path_to/CommonCrypto' }
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/path_to/CommonCrypto' }
```

`user_target_xcconfig` is what allows `PodB` to inject build settings into `PodA`. This is generally not a great idea and could be used to screw up all kinds of things, so I'd welcome a better solution, but in the particular case of pointing parent pods to a module I think it is acceptable.

That said I *think* this solution would fail if `PodA` depended on both `PodB` and `PodC` where both `B` and `C` required `CommonCrypto`...

Answer (score 1):

So far I've had good luck just copying all of the needed CommonCrypto headers into a single bridging header, and including that into the pod. CommonCrypto changes very rarely, and it is reasonably likely that it will be a modular header before any important changes happen to it. See [RNCryptor.h](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/blob/swift/RNCryptor.h) for an example header file. Note that all the `#ifdef` conditionals are included, and each entire header is included (not just what is required for this project). This should protect against multiple packages importing the same file (as long as the header doesn't change).

The [resultant podspec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/blob/swift/RNCryptor.podspec) just includes the `.h` as a source:

```
s.source_files = 'RNCryptor.swift', 'RNCryptor.h'
```

Comment: Yes, I spent awhile trying to understand your `CommonCrypto-Swift` pod before I realized you'd abandoned it for this approach. I was going to try it this way if I couldn't get modulemap method to work. Either way, I hope Apple turn it into a modular header sooner rather than later.

Comment: Yeah; I'm deleting that one. It was an interesting experiment but didn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the framework to podB's spec file?

```
s.frameworks = 'CommonCrypto'
```

Comment: That seems to cause `PodB` to fail at link time. It is looking for a `CommonCrypto` framework and not finding it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't worked with CommonCrypto before. Is it called something else? I see a libcommonCrypto.tdb in my apple supplied frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

using $(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT) instead of $(PODS_ROOT)/podname/ worked for me

```
s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.swift', 'modules/**/*.map'
s.preserve_paths = 'modules/**/*.map'

s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
   'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS[sdk=iphoneos*]'         => '$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/modules/iphoneos/CommonCrypto',
   'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'  => '$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/modules/iphonesimulator/CommonCrypto',
}
```

module.map files:
modules/iphoneos/CommonCrypto/module.map:

```
module CommonCrypto [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
    export *
}
```

modules/iphonesimulator/CommonCrypto/module.map:

```
module CommonCrypto [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
    export *
}
```